# Pronunciations of the geographical name 'Orion'

Tags: pronunciation, geography

Which (3) ways is Orion pronounced as relative to (3) meanings, Orion Township, Lake Orion (Lake), and Lake Orion (town)?

Comment: Pronounced by whom? Personally, I'd pronounce all three the same way.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions the pronunciations.

Comment: In general, place names are pronounced the way the "locals" pronounce them.

Comment: @HotLicks Yup...look at Cairo, Illinois. They pronounce it like "Karo" from the corn syrup.

Comment: @Cascabel - Yep, I was trying to think of that example, but it wasn't coming to me.  Luckily I'm from Louisville, a town that everyone knows how to pronounce correctly!

Answer (score 3):

As far as those examples that exist in Michigan, USA, the pronunciation for all three is the same: OH-ree-un, with the emphasis on the first syllable.
The constellation Orion, on the other hand, is pronounced oh-RY-un, with the emphasis on the second syllable.

For reference, I was born in Michigan, and lived there until my late 40's.  I lived within 30 miles of Orion Twp and Lake Orion (both the town & the lake, obviously ;-)